# RadioButton Group Print Title

Tags: php

All I'm trying to do is print a radio button group along with the group's title.  I figured out how to return and print the group as an array, but how do I return the title as well since I can only return the array of radio button group items?  The title is assigned when I create a new RadioButton item, i.e., "How often do you typically visit XYZ Widget Emporium?"  The code to print the group title would be in the generateHTML() method.

XYZSurvey.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Form.php';
require_once 'RadioButton.php';
require_once 'TextInput.php';
require_once 'Validator.php';

echo "XYZ Wonder Emporium Survey";

$form = new Form();

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("First Name: ", "first_name"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Last Name: ", "last_name"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Age: ", "ice_cream_flavor"));
$radio1 = new RadioButton("Gender:", "gender");
$radio1 -> addOption("Male", "male");
$radio1 -> addOption("Female", "female");
$form -> addInput($radio1);
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Email: ", "email_address"));

$radio2 = new RadioButton("How often do you typically visit XYZ Widget Emporium?");
$radio2 -> addOption("Almost Never", "visit");
$radio2 -> addOption("Once a year", "visit");
$radio2 -> addOption("Once a month", "visit");
$radio2 -> addOption("Weekly", "visit");
$radio2 -> addOption("Daily", "visit");
$form -> addInput($radio2);
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("How did you hear about us? ", "hear_about_us"));
$radio3 = new RadioButton("Have you ever contacted customer service?");
$radio3 -> addOption("Yes", "customer_service");
$radio3 -> addOption("No", "customer_service");
$form -> addInput($radio3);

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("What did we do well? ", "well"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("What could we improve? ", "improve"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Would you recommend XYZ Widget Emporium? ", "recommend"));
$form -> addInput(new TextInput("Additional comments: ", "additional_comments"));

$form -> addInput(new TextInput("", "","Submit","","",false,"submit"));

echo $form -> generateHTML();
```

RadioButton.php

```
<?php

require_once 'TextInput.php';

class RadioButton extends TextInput
{
    const TYPE2 = "radio";
    private $options = array();
    private $required = false;
    private $selected = false;
    private $title;
    private $type;
    public $radiobutton = "";

    function __construct($title = "", $name = "", $selected = false, $type = self::TYPE2)
    {
        $this -> title = $title;
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> selected = $selected;
        $this -> type = $type;
    }

    function addOption(string $label, string $name)
    {
        $this->options[] = ['label' => $label, 'name' => $name,];
    }

    public function generateHTML():string
    {
        $req = "";

        if ($this -> required == true)
        {
            $req = self::$REQUIRED;
        }

        // How do I print the title? return "<title>$this->title</title>"?

        return join('', array_map(function($item)
        {return sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s"> <label>%s</label><br/>', $item['name'], $item['label']);}
         , $this->options))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the *title* along with the html for the options, like below. And the [<title> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) should only be used in the `<head>` section, not in the body:

> The HTML  element defines the title of the document, shown in a browser's title bar or on the page's tab. It can only contain text, and any contained tags are ignored.

So I would recommend using a `div` or `span` and applying a classname like `title` so you could apply css rules to that class if you wanted.

Also, it appears that the `req` property isn't even used so you don't have to assign a value to `$req` unless you are going to use that in the return value.

```
public function generateHTML():string
{
    return sprintf('<div class="title">%s</div>',$this->title).' '.join('', array_map(function($item)
    {return sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s"> <label>%s</label><br/>', $item['name'], $item['label']);}
     , $this->options));
}
```

Comment: What you suggest makes sense, thank you!  However, I got an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in /home/ar04063/public_html/RadioButton.php on line 39"

Comment: It appears that you have two extra closing parentheses `))` after the `join('',array_map(...` - see my updated answer

Comment: If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark to the left of it. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.